# Convert two one dimensional arrays to one two dimensional array- Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, function

I have two arrays, say *A* and *B*. I want to convert it into one two dimensional array.
Example:

```
A=[1;2;3];
B=[1;2;3];
```

The output should be

```
C=[[1,1];[2,2];[3,3]];
```

Is there any MATLAB function or any simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to concatenate two vectors, the most simplest way will be,

**Example:**

```
% Create two vector (row wise)
A=[1;2;3];
B=[1;2;3];

% Concatenate the vectors into coloumn
C =[A B]
```

**Command window output:**

```
C =
         1     1
         2     2
         3     3
```

Comment: I need one more help. How can we find intersection of 2D arrays in matlab?

Comment: I think easiest way will be to take the difference and check for zero, if the two matrix elements intersect each other than it will be give zero as a different. Then find the element which has this difference as zero.

This could be a different question, but I am pretty sure it has already been answered. So if this does not help then try searching in SO

Comment: In case you are sure and did not find the answer or question already asked then do not hesitate to open a new question.

Comment: Just an initial search gave me a function of matlab `intersect` that will work as you stated. Read  `doc intersect`

Comment: That is working for 1D array only. Can you please try for 2D array once? I am unable to get the desired answer.

Comment: It also works for matrices but you have to provide an appropriate flag.
This question is already answered at [Intersection of two 7x2 matrix](https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/35749-intersection-of-two-7x2-matrix)